# Who introduced the difference between magnetic fields in matter? $\mathbf H$ vs $\mathbf B$

Tags: physics, physicists, magnetism

In magnetism, there are two different magnetic fields, that I will simply call $\mathbf B$ and $\mathbf H$. The distinction is not always clear. In experiments $\mathbf H$ is the applied field while $\mathbf B$ is the total field that includes the magnetization $\mathbf M$ of matter. The three fields are unified under the equation
$$\mathbf H=\frac{1}{\mu_0}\mathbf B-\mathbf M.$$

Who was the first to make this distinction?

Comment: Can you access "B and H, the intensity vectors of magnetism: A new approach to resolving a century-old controversy" in *American Journal of Physics*? https://doi.org/10.1119/1.19459

Comment: If I recall correctly, this B and H symbolism is due to Maxwell.

Comment: @M.Farooq Maxwell introduced the notation but not the concept. But thanks for the reference!